# Jquery flip script not showing unique content on flip back side

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement Rotate3Di, found here: http://www.zachstronaut.com/projects/rotate3di/

I can get my images to flip, but the back side is only showing a mirror image of the front and not unique content that I am pulling from a database. Thanks for any help in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#movienav li div.back').hide().css('left', 0);

    function mySideChange(front) {
        if (front) {
            $(this).parent().find('div.front').show();
            $(this).parent().find('div.back').hide();

        } else {
            $(this).parent().find('div.front').hide();
            $(this).parent().find('div.back').show();
        }
    }

    $('#movienav li').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).find('div').stop().rotate3Di('flip', 180, 1000, {direction: 'clockwise', sideChange: mySideChange});
        },
        function () {
            $(this).find('div').stop().rotate3Di('unflip', 1000, {sideChange: mySideChange});
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

***HTML***

```
<div id="movienav">
<ul>
<li><div class="front"><img src="<?php echo $imglink; ?>" width="340" height="450" class="dvdcover" /></div>
<div class="back">
<?php echo $description; ?>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
#movienav {
    height: 450px;
    width:75%; 
    float:left;
    margin-top:25px; 
    clear:left;
    padding-bottom: 45px;
}

#movienav li {
    width: 340px;
    height: 450px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    display:inline;
    list-style:none;
}

#movienav li div {
    width: 340px;
    height: 450px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #161616;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#movienav li div.back {
    left: -999em;
    padding-bottom: 15px;  
    background-color:#161616; /*max-height:450px; overflow:auto;*/
    margin-top: 0;

}
```

***SOLVED***

Changed above lines to:

```
$('#movienav li').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).find('div').stop().rotate3Di('180', 400, {direction: 'clockwise', sideChange: mySideChange});
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find('div').stop().rotate3Di('unflip', 400, {sideChange: mySideChange});
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip

I think you want `backface-visibility: hidden;`

I'll be honest I've only done this via CSS and not with javascript, but I had the same issue at first until I set the `backface-visibility`. Doing everything via javascript might require some extra magic.

Comment: Where would I add that in the css? I just tried #movienav li div and #movienav li div.back and no luck. I want the back content I have written to show, NOT the back of the movie dvd cover, which it is currently showing

Comment: I think you want it on both the front and back divs. Basically the way these usually work is the front and back are positioned on top of each other, and just run a flip animation. The back starts out on its reverse side so hidden via the backface-visibility. When flipped each the front is now hidden and the back is now shown. I am not completley sure using your plugin. I'll play with it a see what I can figure out. I personally would just use CSS3. Only IE users will miss out.

Comment: I'll play with your code. It looks like he's only using skew in combination with display: block/none. So I am guessing some CSS is overriding the javascript or the elements aren't positioned/ordered correctly. I'll try some stuff.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate that...been at this all day.

Comment: Well I do not know what to tell you. You shouldn't need the show hide stuff you have in the call back as the documentation clearly states: `If you rotate an object with rotate3Di and specify a sideChange callback function, the flip side of the object will not show up mirrored / reversed.` However I cannot get it to work either. It has something to do with the `left` property on the back though.

Comment: I think there is a bug or something. Look at this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ENZu5/3/ Side change only fires when its flipped back, not when it's flipper over. So something is strange. I would use CSS3. Would you like a CSS3 example. Only IE users won't get the flip effect. They will still see the reverse side, just not the effect.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wQpB9/ You can use this for CSS if you want. The opacity is for IE. If you leave the opacity off, you'll need a javascript fallback for IE. I usually just do a show/hide for IE users. If the want a crappy browser, they get a crappier experience, but functionality is still there.